# Android's realm.io how to sync with server side MySQL DB

Tags: android, realm

I am working on an Android app using realm db as my local db, how do I sync my records in realm with my server side MySQL db?

Comment: You can't sync automatically with MySQL DB, but there is auto-synchronization with the Realm Object Server.

Comment: But @EpicPandaForce - is there a way to ***sync the ROS with an existing Sql database***?  In that way you could have an existing SQL database (for a big web site), and just start and sync an ROS to that sql database (I mean server to server).  And then easily sync the apps to the ROS, within Realm.  What do you think?

Comment: @JoeBlow The SQL database won't be able to sync to the ROS unless you use the enterprise edition, which costs an unknown amount of money :P otherwise you can sync to it like any other server: manually downloading the data with REST (or get notifications about it through GCM or websocket)

Comment: hi @EpicPandaForce - thanks a million for the reply - yes, absolutely assume I have the Enterprise edition, that's a non-issue.  Just to clarify.  Regarding the (enterprise) R-O-S *running on a server*.  You're saying there's a way to sync  that (enterprise) R-O-S *running on a server*, with a normal SQL database running on a server (say, an ordinary Amazon RDS). If so that's - incredible.  What is the software package one has to install on the two servers, to do that??  Where is it mentioned on realm.io?

Comment: I find the whole issue very confusing.  I know that the (enterprise) R-O-S *running on a server* will completely sync ***TO PHONES*** ... {indeed, you have to have the *enterprise* ROS-on-a-server to sync *to phones* - if you have the *free* ROS-on-a-server you're not allowed to sync *to phones*}.  But my issue is, syncing the ROS-on-a-server ***to another server (eg, an ordinary AmazonRDS sql database)***.  Any ideas?!  It's a mess right!  heh!

Comment: @JoeBlow well the ROS allows you to sync objects between phones through the ROS to other phones. The sync doesn't do anything for an ordinary AmazonRDS sql database. You'd have to create a backend with a REST API as you normally would.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - that's Epic.  Well it's bad news, but it's epic you're confirming the bad news, heh.  Yeah, I thought that might be the case.  Perhaps in the future they'll cover that "angle".  Building true offline syncing is a huge project.

Answer (score 8):

**Update from 27 Septermber 2016:**

Realm now fully supports synchronizing data against Realm Object Server. More details are available [here](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-mobile-platform/).

**19 June 2016**

There is no such way - the Realm doesn't have such mechanisms, and it is logical. You mix different approaches - syncing data and storing locally (the mission of Realm, SQLite and other Android mobile DBs). You can do it by your own custom implementation ([like in the tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/)), or using by [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html?hl=en).

Comment: Well that synchronization works against the Realm Object Server, not with his MySQL database

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - right - all these posts that say "Realm now syncs phones with a server!"are incredibly confusing ........... because Realm now syncs phones ***>>> with the Realm ROS server <<<***.  The big issue, and the question above, is syncing with an ordinary SQL database. (Say AmazonRDS - just an ordinary sql-style database on a server.)

Comment: It's utterly amazing that realm-phones sync with a ROS-server.  But the whole world wants to know how to use Realm-phones as s solution to syncing phones with a normal SQL site.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexander already said, you cannot automatically sync your local Realm db with a server-side MySQL db. However, you can implement a straight-forward custom solution which uses a server-side REST API to manifest changes of the local database.
You basically just observe your local database for changes (which is really easy in Realm) and call the REST API accordingly when something changes.
A SyncService implementation could be something like this:

```
class SyncService {
    private let realm: Realm
    private let tokens: [NotificationToken]

    init(modelTypes: [Syncable.Type], realm: Realm = try! Realm()) {
        self.realm = realm

        tokens = modelTypes.map { modelType in
            modelType.registerNotificationObserver(for: realm, callback: SyncService.handleUpdate)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You can find more information [in this article](https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/sync-realm-with-server/?utm_source=so) where the author implements a one-way sync using Realm with a simple REST API

Answer (score 0):

Realm is syncing with server side scripting Node.JS 4.x. And it's not free.
Event handling, server-side data access available in Professional/Enterprise Edition.
In server-side you may add change listiner, then to RDBMS. Look at https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#event-handling

Free way

You may add on Realm.addListener when it change send to server use WS/HTTP Request. But if application offline you need more logic